# using svn in struts projects created by maven

Tags: svn, maven, struts

I have created a struts project by issuing maven command .now i have the directory structure.My friend wants to work in the same project from different machine using svn.

what should we do ? how to configure things please ?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a subversion repository on a system which can be shared between the two (it could be either of your workstation or a common system) and then check-in the created project to the repository.

Subsequently, both of you can checkout and work on the project concurrently.